# Output of Laravel datatable

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.4, adminlte

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Datatable 7.x. I am using AdminLTE also. I need a column named 'Status'. I wrote below code in **controller**.

```
return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('status', function(Users $users){
                $status     =   (($users->status == 1)?
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'
                                    :
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>'
                                );

                $html       =   '<div class="btn-group">
                                    '.$status.'
                                </div>';

                return $html;
            })
            ->setRowId('id')
            ->make(true);
```

My output is like below

[image]

But I need the button. Can anyone help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use html or views in the `setColumn` method then you need to declare the columns in the [`rawColumns`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns) method so that it doesn't escape the HTML.

```
 return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('status', function(Users $users){
                $status     =   (($users->status == 1)?
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'
                                    :
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>'
                                );

                $html       =   '<div class="btn-group">
                                    '.$status.'
                                </div>';

                return $html;
            })
            ->setRowId('id')
            ->rawColumns(['status'])
            ->make(true);
```

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns